How to connect to a server on a local network using an external domain name?
I have  domain "example.com". The Internet router  (192.168.0.1) forwards specific ports to a router within the network working in WISP mode (192.168.1.1 / 192.168.0.123).
That router has a DMZ, redirecting all connections to server 192.168.1.123.
I can connect to "example.com" from outside of the network and from devices connected to 192.168.0.1.
Devices on 192.168.1.1 timeout connecting to example.com. I can connect using IP address 192.168.1.123 with no issues, and I can  connect to 192.168.1.1 using it's external IP (192.168.0.123) and get redirected to the server.
What could be the cause for this?
It doesn't work for SSH, HTTPS, IMAP and SMTP, so it's not something specific to a port or protocol.

@vidarlo to be honest, I cannot answer that. This topic appears to be way more advanced than I expected and I hardly understand the answers under that question. I understood that the problem most likely comes from the src ip and dst ip both being local?
